# Is $E(Y|X)=0, a.s.$ equivalent to $E[Y\cdot f(X)]=0, \forall f\in \mathscr{B}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Is the statement below true? How to prove it?
$$E(Y|X)=0, a.s.$$
is equivalent to 
$$E[Y\cdot f(X)]=0, \forall f\in \mathscr{B}$$

---

If $E(Y|X)=0, a.s.$, then $E[Y\cdot f(X)]=E\{E[Y\cdot f(X)|X]\}=E[f(X)\cdot E(Y|X)]=0$. How to prove the opposite part?

Comment: What is $\mathscr{B}$?

Comment: $f(x)$ is Borel measurable function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f=I_A$. You get $EYI_A(X)=0$ which means $EYI_{X^{-1}(A)}=0$. By definition of conditional expectation this give $E(Y|X)=0$. [Note that $\sigma (X)$ is precisely the collection of sets $\{X^{-1}(A):A\in \mathcal B\}$.